# WordPress REST API - Get media of specific type only

Tags: wordpress, api, rest, filter

I am using WP REST API v1.2.5 (as v2 doesn't seem to work on the website I'm working on) and I want to retrieve all pdf objects from Media without getting all the other images, videos etc. How could I do this (without adding a custom endpoint if possible).

to get all media I use:

```
/wp-json/media
```

I can't find a filter that would only return the pdfs on my site though. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: have you tried anything with code ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have pdfs in your media library, this works for me:

```
<your_wordpress_install_base_url>/wp-json/wp/v2/media?search=.pdf
```

Or for example to display 25 .jpg images per page, by page number:

```
<your_wordpress_install_base_url>/wp-json/wp/v2/media?search=.jpg&per_page=25
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution thanks to this post:
https://1fix.io/blog/2015/02/28/wordpress-rest-api-media/

Basically you need to add the following php code to the WP REST API plugin:

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', function( $query_vars ) {
    $query_vars[] = 'post_parent';
    return $query_vars;
});
```

This enables media to be filtered by post parent (which for some reason isn't available by default) using the following syntax:

```
.../wp-json/media?filter[post_parent]=YOUR_ID
```

So if I want to get all media attached to an article with ID 984, I would do this:

```
.../wp-json/media?filter[post_parent]=984
```

I hope this helps anyone else facing the same problem.